# how to group data after every change but not to merge group even if the next time value repeated in sql

Tags: sql, t-sql

i have to group data on basis of amount column but if the amount repeat after some interval then it should be treated as new group.e.g

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TEST](
    [ID] [INT] NULL,
    [DLRCODE] [VARCHAR](20) NULL,
    [AMN] [DECIMAL](21, 5) NULL,
    [RATE] [DECIMAL](7, 5) NULL,
    [DTE] [DATETIME] NULL
) ON [NFS_DATA]
```

---

-----this should be first group

```
1   123 10.00000    5.00000 2019-11-01 00:00:00.000
2   123 10.00000    5.00000 2019-11-02 00:00:00.000
3   123 10.00000    5.00000 2019-11-03 00:00:00.000
-----this should be second group
4   123 15.00000    5.00000 2019-11-04 00:00:00.000
-----this should be third group
5   123 10.00000    5.00000 2019-11-05 00:00:00.000
6   123 10.00000    5.00000 2019-11-06 00:00:00.000
-----this should be fourth group
7   123 20.00000    5.00000 2019-11-07 15:02:07.537
```

as you can check from above code and data, result should be group, every time amount change new group will be created.

result will like this

```
1 30  --- group of first three records
2 15  --- group of fourth records
3 20  --- group of  fifth and sixth records
4 20  --- group of seven record
```

Comment: It's great you've posted the table's DDL, but the sample data should be posted as DML, otherwise the DDL is worthless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using a combination of `LAG` and conditional aggregation:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT Id
        , DLRCode
        , Amn
        , Rate
        , DTE
        , ISNULL(LAG(Amn) OVER(ORDER BY DTE), Amn) As PreviousAmount
    FROM dbo.Test
)

SELECT  Id
        , DLRCode
        , Amn
        , Rate
        , DTE
        , SUM(IIF(Amn = PreviousAmount, 0, 1)) OVER(ORDER BY DTE) As Grp
FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

To get your result set, you only need `lag()`, taking both the date and the amount into account:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(amn) over (partition by dlrcode, rate order by dte) as prev_amn,
             lag(dte) over (partition by dlrcode, rate order by dte) as prev_dte
      from test t
     ) t
where prev_amn is null or
      prev_amn <> amn or
      prev_dte < dateadd(day, -1, dte);
```

If you want to incorporate this into a group id and then summarize the groups -- with information from multiple rows -- then we'll add a group id as the cumulative sum of the group changes and aggregate:

```
select dlrcode, rate, amn, min(dte), max(dte),
       count(*)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_amn = amn and prev_dte >= dateadd(day, -1, dte)
                      then 0 else 1
                 end) over (partition by dlrcode, rate) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(amn) over (partition by dlrcode, rate order by dte) as prev_amn,
                   lag(dte) over (partition by dlrcode, rate order by dte) as prev_dte
            from test t
           ) t
     ) t
group by dlrcode, rate, amn, grp;
```